# Convert a string representation of UUIDTools:UUID back to UUIDTools:UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, object, uuid

I have a scenario, where in I have a uuid in a string format. This uuid originally belonged to UUIDTools::UUID class (and was already converted to_s before passing on to my method). Now, I need to convert it back to object of type - UUIDTools::UUID, as I need to invoke few methods specific to UUIDTools::UUID class. Any clean way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`UUIDTools::UUID.parse`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/uuidtools/2.1.5/UUIDTools/UUID#parse-class_method):

```
 require "uuidtools"

 uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create
 uuid.to_s
 #=> "cd833ba3-97c5-4615-a2a0-a6c3e56b24b2"

 UUIDTools::UUID.parse("cd833ba3-97c5-4615-a2a0-a6c3e56b24b2")
 #=> <UUID:0x3fd33d0ac184 UUID:cd833ba3-97c5-4615-a2a0-a6c3e56b24b2>

 UUIDTools::UUID.parse(uuid.to_s) == uuid
 #=> true
```